# Нужна помощь в upload file C# application form

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, visual-studio

Всем добрый день. 
Пишу приложение для ПК. У меня есть PictureBox в котором отображается изображение документов. В БД mysql хранятся ссылки на изображения. 
Так вот у меня данная схема работает только на одно компе . Мне нужно загружать файл в серверм через приложение ПК и и брать ссылку этого изображения , для того чтобы любой пользватель в этой сети мог просматривать в документ. Как upload- кать в сервер или есть другие пути данной проблемы ? 
Пишу на C# в среде Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Скажите, правильно ли я понял ситуацию? У Вас есть БД, в которой хранятся ссылки на некие картинки. Есть приложение, которое позволяет показывать эти картинки. Сейчас приложение работает на одной машине (то есть БД находится на ней же). Вам надо сделать приложение многопользовательским. Жду ответа, постараюсь помочь.

Comment: Да именно так )

Comment: В Вашем случае необходимо создать серверное приложение, которое будет отдавать клиентам изображения, раз пишете на C#, приложение стоит разрабатывать на ASP.NET. Клиентское приложение необходимо переписать так, чтобы оно обращалось не к локальной БД, а к Вашему веб-приложению. Это можно сделать, например, при помощи HttpClient. Соответственно, с БД работает веб-приложение.

Answer (score -1):

Как по мне, лучше всего в твоем случае- хранить в базе именно **изображение**, а не **ссылку** на него.
Один из способов  - использовать поле "varbinary", и в коде C# переобразовать изображение в масив байтов.
вот, например, как реализовано здесь:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/e628d9/inserting-retrieving-images-from-sql-server-database-without-using-stored-procedures/